# Objective C: Create a new View in touches end

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I'm trying to do a program that everytime my touches end, another UIView will appear using a loop for as many as UIView I want. How can I set a loop of UIView in my touches end? or should I create it in viewDidLoad and call it in touches end?

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon leaving
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
            UIImageView *layerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
            [layerView setAlpha:.05];
            [self.view addSubview:layerView];
        }
    }
```

Hope you can help me guys..

Comment: What do yo want to do? Add one view after touch or 100?

Comment: add one view after touch ended, and the limit is 100 views. Actually i just made that limitation, much better if i can create an infinite view.

Comment: You just want to add a layerView for each tap? Then what's the loop for?

Comment: It's just came up to my mind that I need to use a loop. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Also I want to retain my previous view.

Comment: What do you mean by retain? You want the added view transparent so you can still see the previous view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a single view after each tap, you don't need a for loop. Just do

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon leaving
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    UIImageView *layerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    [layerView setAlpha:.05];

    // If you just want to add a line, add another uiview would the easiest way. For example:
    UIView *line = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, layerView.center.y, layerView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [layerView addSubview:line];

    [self.view addSubview:layerView];
}
```

Of course, you can also subclass a UIView and draw whatever you want in

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

Comment: the missing part is that i want to create a drawing in each view. How can the touchesBegan will know that i'm writing in that view? Should i use this layerView[i]? and declare i++ in the touches end?

Comment: Yes i want it to be transparent and want to see the previous view

Comment: Ok, so after each tap, you want to add another view and draw something in each previous view?